# Проблема установки RVM на Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Пытаюсь установить программу, но к сожалению не получается в силу причин моего не знания. Начинаю устанавливать как указано на на сайте RVM, т.е.

```
gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3 7D2BAF1CF37B13E2069D6956105BD0E739499BDB
```

в итоге получаю такой ответ:

```
gpg: key 105BD0E739499BDB: 3 подписи не проверены за отсутствием ключа
gpg: ключ 105BD0E739499BDB: "Piotr Kuczynski <piotr.kuczynski@gmail.com>" не изменен
gpg: key 3804BB82D39DC0E3: 96 подписей не проверено за отсутствием ключа
gpg: ключ 3804BB82D39DC0E3: "Michal Papis (RVM signing) <mpapis@gmail.com>" не изменен
gpg: Всего обработано: 2
gpg: неизмененных: 2
```

после пишу в терминале следущее:

```
\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```

И на этом месте начинается сущий ад:

```
Downloading https://github.com/rvm/rvm/archive/1.29.4.tar.gz
Downloading https://github.com/rvm/rvm/releases/download/1.29.4/1.29.4.tar.gz.asc
gpg: Подпись сделана Вс 01 июл 2018 22:41:26 MSK
gpg:                ключом RSA с идентификатором 62C9E5F4DA300D94AC36166BE206C29FBF04FF17
gpg: Действительная подпись пользователя "Michal Papis (RVM signing) <mpapis@gmail.com>" [неизвестно]
gpg:                 или "Michal Papis <michal.papis@toptal.com>" [неизвестно]
gpg:                 или "[jpeg image of size 5015]" [неизвестно]
gpg:     Внимание: Данный ключ не заверен доверенной подписью!
gpg:          Нет указаний на то, что подпись принадлежит владельцу.
Отпечаток первичного ключа: 409B 6B17 96C2 7546 2A17  0311 3804 BB82 D39D C0E3
 Отпечаток подключа: 62C9 E5F4 DA30 0D94 AC36  166B E206 C29F BF04 FF17
GPG verified '/usr/share/rvm/archives/rvm-1.29.4.tgz'
tar: binscripts: Функция utime завершилась с ошибкой: Операция не позволена
tar:     config/solaris: Функция utime завершилась с ошибкой: Операция не позволена
tar: config: Функция utime завершилась с ошибкой: Операция не позволена
tar: contrib/hudson: Функция utime завершилась с ошибкой: Операция не позволена
tar: contrib: Функция utime завершилась с ошибкой: Операция не позволена
tar:     docs: Функция utime завершилась с ошибкой: Операция не позволена
tar: examples: Функция utime завершилась с ошибкой: Операция не позволена
tar: gem-cache: Функция utime завершилась с ошибкой: Операция не позволена
tar: gemsets/jruby: Функция utime завершилась с ошибкой: Операция не позволена
tar: gemsets/ruby/1.8.5: Функция utime завершилась с ошибкой: Операция не позволена
tar: gemsets/ruby/1.8.6: Функция utime завершилась с ошибкой: Операция не позволена
tar: gemsets/ruby/1.8.7: Функция utime завершилась с ошибкой: Операция не позволена
tar: gemsets/ruby: Функция utime завершилась с ошибкой: Операция не позволена
tar:     gemsets: Функция utime завершилась с ошибкой: Операция не позволена
tar: help/gemset: Функция utime завершилась с ошибкой: Операция не позволена
tar: help/rvmrc: Функция utime завершилась с ошибкой: Операция не позволена
tar: help: Функция utime завершилась с ошибкой: Операция не позволена
tar: hooks: Функция utime завершилась с ошибкой: Операция не позволена
tar: lib/rvm: Функция utime завершилась с ошибкой: Операция не позволена
tar: lib: Функция utime завершилась с ошибкой: Операция не позволена
tar: man/man1: Функция utime завершилась с ошибкой: Операция не позволена
tar: man: Функция utime завершилась с ошибкой: Операция не позв
```

Подскажите пожалуйста!

Установил, но все равно проблема при выполнении :

```
rvm get stable
```

Так же выводит кучу строк:

```
Функция utime завершилась с ошибкой: Операция не позволена
```

Comment: Видимо проблемы с правами на запись для пользователя

Comment: пробовали через sudo?

Comment: @Elanyl да, пробовал и через sudo и через gpg2

Comment: попробуйте данную [инструкцию](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-with-rvm-on-ubuntu-18-04), может поможет

Comment: перешел на docker и больше нет проблем, хочешь так, хочешь этак, "работает как часы", иногда правда использую локальный Ruby, но редко совсем

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Была такая же проблема.

Отключала ipv6 по совету из [этой статьи](https://rvm.io/rvm/security), но [другим способом](https://losst.ru/kak-otklyuchit-ipv6-ubuntu-16-04).

Далее вот [этот мануал](http://citforum.ru/security/cryptography/gph/ch01.shtml) по gpg, для изменения доверия ключа.

И команда rvmsudo rvm cleanup all  из [этой ветки](https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/4345)

Answer (score 0):

Получилось установить RVM и RoR, а так же получилось запустить пуму в качестве доказательства работы. Сделал частично с помощью этих инструкций:

```
https://rvm.io/rvm/security 
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-with-rvm-on-ubuntu-18-04
```